# Object Data Path Input node needed in Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

There is Object Data Path Output but no Input

How can I manipulate spline Bevel Curve Points Radiuses with Animation Nodes?

How to get array of splines[0].bezier_points[n].radius, 
modify it and copy to other spline. 
Input spline is freehand drawn with tablet.

Comment: I've asked myself the same question. My though is you need to use a script expression (and the corresponding node in AN). But I did not tested it.

Comment: Jacques implemented this feature to Spline Info node lately. You will see it in the next release I bet.

Answer (score 1):

*Spline Info* node can be used to get the radii of the points, while *Set Spline Radius* node can be used to set the radii of the points.

[image: Node Tree]